# Why doesn't ruby detect an invalid encoding while mysql does?

Tags: mysql, ruby, utf-8, internationalization, utf8mb4

I'm pulling some RSS feeds in from YouTube which have invalid UTF8. I can create a similar ruby string using

```
bad_utf8 = "\u{61B36}"
bad_utf8.encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
bad_utf8.valid_encoding? # => true
```

Ruby thinks this is a valid UTF-8 encoding and I'm pretty sure it isn't.

When talking to Mysql I get an error like so

```
require 'mysql2'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
client.query("use test");

bad_utf8 = "\u{61B36}"
client.query("INSERT INTO utf8 VALUES ('#{moo}')")

# Incorrect string value: '\xF1\xA1\xAC\xB6' for column 'string' at row 1 (Mysql2::Error)
```

How can I detect or fix up these invalid types of encodings before I send them off to MySQL?

Comment: So I think the problem might be that MySQL only supports the Basic MultiLingual Plane where as ruby supports everything.

Comment: Ruby supports everything? Since when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly because the code point doesn't lie in the [basic multilingual plane](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) 
 which is the only characters that MySQL allows in its "utf8" character set.

Newer versions of mysql have another character set called "utf8mb4" which [supports unicode characters outside the BMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

But you probably don't want to be using that. Consider your use-cases carefully. Few real human languages (if any) use characters outside the BMP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't rely on Ruby's built-in String.valid_encoding?, because the following is also possible:

```
irb
1.9.3-p125 :001 > bad_utf8 = "\u{0}"
 => "\u0000" 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > bad_utf8.valid_encoding?
 => true 
1.9.3-p125 :003 > bad_utf8.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

This is valid UTF-8 (Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8), but I found the presence of the NULL character in a string is often a hint to a previous conversion error (e.g. when transcoding from invalid encoding informations found in html pages).

I created my own validation function for "Modified UTF-8", which can take a :bmp_only option for restricting validation to the Basic Multilingual Plane (0x1-0xffff). This should be enough for most modern languages (Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_plane).

Find the validator here: https://gist.github.com/2295531

Comment: \u0000 is valid. It's exclusion is within the context of "Modified UTF-8" used by Java DataInput/DataOutput http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html

Comment: That's correct. The above gist makes usage of Modified UTF-8, I will make a note there to make it clearer.